# How to make sure not to dispose objects that are still used by others

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, dispose

I have a class that use constructor injections.

```
public class MyClass
{                       
    public MyClass(IInterface1 interface1)
    {            
    }

    public Dispose()
    {
       interface1.dispose();
    }
}
```

interface1 will be injected by DI. But sometimes, i need to create MyClass manually.

```
public class MyOtherClass
{                       
    private readonly IInterface1 _interface1;

    public MyOtherClass()
    {
      _interface1 = new Interface1();
    }       

    public Foo()
    {
       foo = new MyClass(_interface1);
       bar = new MyClass(_interface1);
    }
}
```

in my dispose method, interface1 is always disposed when MyClass is destroyed. The problem is, interface1 is own by MyOtherClass and might still be used by other instances and shouldn't be disposed. How can i resolve this?

Comment: Why you disposing in `MyClass`? You should dispose interface in `MyOtherClass` then it is not used anymore.

Comment: Do you need to pass the same instance of `Interface1` to all instances of `MyClass`? If no, then create different instances and pass them to `MyClass` instances.

Comment: Also, I agree with @Reniuz, disposing `interface1` is responsibility of the class that created it - `MyOtherClass`.

Comment: But what if interface1 is injected by Dependency Injection to MyClass? Shouldn't i dispose interface1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call

```
interface1.dispose();
```

inside MyClass.

If interface1 is created by the DI container, it will be rleased there.
If you are creating it explicitly as in MyOtherClass, Dispose it in MyOtherClass.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I thought we have to always dispose objects created by DI container.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code.

First of all, `MyClass` 'illegally' takes the ownership of the `IInterface1`, while it has no idea what the lifetime of that instances is. This means that if `IInterface1` is reused, the system breaks.

The basic rule of ownership is that "he who creates an instance is responsible of disposing it" (the [RAII idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)). Since `MyClass` didn't create `IInterface1`, he should not dispose it. `MyClass` should therefore not implement a `Dispose` method and not call `IInterface1.Dispose()`.

Second, by letting the `IInterface1` implement `IDisposable`, your code violates the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (DIP), because the DIP states:

> Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on
>   abstractions.

Your `IInterface1` however, depends on an implementation detail, because whether or not some component has unmanaged resources that needs to be disposed is an implementation detail. It is very unlikely that every implementation of that `IInterface1` will always need to dispose resources and because of that your interface leaks implementation details of a specific implementation.

So instead of letting the `IInterface1` implement `IDisposable` you simply let the given implementation implement `IDisposable`. What's nice about this is that it minimized `IInterface1`'s API, which makes it easier to work with and possibly allows you to conform to the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

If you do that, the problem goes away immediately, since `MyClass` has no clue whether or not `IInterface1` can be disposed or not (which is good), which means it can't accidentally call `Dispose` in the first place.

This of course leaves the disposal of that instance up to the part of the system that created that instance (which is good). If this instance is created on your behalf by a DI library (if you use one), the DI library is usually responsible of disposing that instance. If you don't use a container, you will have to ensure disposal yourself obviously.

Do note that not all containers track all instances. For instance, Unity and Simple Injector do not track (and dispose) transient instances automatically. In most cases however, disposable components should be registered with a scoped lifestyle (per web request or something similar). I think in that case all containers dispose instances that are registered with such lifestyle.

Comment: There are times when it is necessary, right, and proper for a method to take ownership of an `IDisposable` which is passed to it (e.g. a helper method which accepts a socket, calls `DuplicateAndClose` on it, serializes the returned `SocketInformation` to a string, and returns that), and times when it is necessary, right, and proper for a method to yields ownership of an `IDisposable` to its caller (e.g. `IEnumerator<T>.GetEnumerator()`).  What's essential, however, is that *transfers of ownership be clearly documented*.  Additionally...

Comment: ...if an object will upon construction acquire ownership of a resource, it may be better to construct the object using a factory method that stores it to an `out` parameter than to use a constructor.  A method which uses an `out` parameter can ensure that it will either store to the `out` parameter a reference to an object which owns the resource, or else dispose of the resource itself.  Using a constructor runs the risk that an exception could occur at a time when the "ownership transfer" is incomplete, leaving the resource in limbo.

Comment: @supercat: agreed about the documentation. Sometimes you need to transfer ownership and you want to make that very clear in the docs or through the API. But even better than good documentation is good coding practices. Factories for instance are an obvious place where ownership is transformed; but constructors are not! The .NET framework has some places where it violates this and developers keep tripping over this, over and over again.