# Will Ninject Dispose of an Object that doesn't have IDisposable on it's Interface, but does on it's implementation?

Tags: interface, ninject, idisposable

Suppose I have an interface for an object that implements `IDisposable`, such as this one that I use for my Entity Framework DbContext:

```
public interface IMyContext : IDisposable
{
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    DbSet Set(Type entityType);
    int SaveChanges();
    IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult> GetValidationErrors();
    DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity:class;
    DbEntityEntry Entry(object entity);
}
```

If I was to remove the declaration for `IDisposable` on this **interface**, like below:

```
public interface IMyContext // : IDisposable -- Commented out IDisposable
{
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    DbSet Set(Type entityType);
    int SaveChanges();
    IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult> GetValidationErrors();
    DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity:class;
    DbEntityEntry Entry(object entity);
}
```

Would Ninject still be able to dispose of my DbContext if I used this interface to resolve it?

IE: Does Ninject check the object that is being resolved to detect IDisposable, even if it is missing on the interface?

Comment: It does. But you should really try that out yourself. Or see the source code of ninject.

Comment: The `IMyContext` should not implement `IDisposable`. You are violating the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) by doing this. For more information, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26758168/264697).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that's how you can verify it for yourself:

```
public interface IFoo { }

public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("got disposed");
    }
}

var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Get<IFoo>();
kernel.Dispose();
```

if you can see "got disposed" .. well.. it got disposed.. if not.. it didn't!
Of course feel free to replace the `Console.WriteLine` with a static boolean flag or so..